# How to compare several unordered list and get the list names if there are matching values

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have several lists containing values. just like below.

```
Alc=['P-111127759','111157751','1123104714']
FItems=['1123104714','797917266','79791761','79791765','79791763']
kuVItem=['1110234713','161231437','756623557','1123104714','7630672177', '754955924','712969245','963176673','181104711']
Products=['7171523315','Pqw-805967111','1150596117','115596116']
WProducts=['PQ-4559678','7171523315','5505296117','755961146']
```

I basically want to find out the list names if there are any values similar in lists.
For example, Alc, FItems, and kuVItem lists have the same value, "1123104714". So I basically want those names as pairs. I mean like this

```
['Alc', 'FItems'],['Alc', 'kuVItem'],['FItems','kuVItem']
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do the lists have to come from python variables? What is creating them this way? Could it be changed to use a dict?

Comment: How and why are the names changing every time? If you don't know the names of the lists then how are you going to reference them to compare them?

Comment: I don't know if lists are the correct structure for this. Will you rewrite the code every time? You could use a dictionary where the key is the list name, and the value is the list of values. Would make much more sense from an usability standpoint, and make a solution to this problem much simpler.

Comment: Yes it can be changed to Dic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assumed that the values are gonna be supplied through a dictionary(which is the only way I can think of for named values whose name change often).

Then just iterate through the keys, and for each key, compare the value with other entries. Since we just want to know if there is overlap, `set.intersection()` is a great tool for this.

My code ended up being:

```
my_dict = {
  'Alc':['P-111127759','111157751','1123104714'],
  'FItems':['1123104714','797917266','79791761','79791765','79791763'],
  'kuVItem':['1110234713','161231437','756623557','1123104714','7630672177', '754955924','712969245','963176673','181104711'],
  'Products':['7171523315','Pqw-805967111','1150596117','115596116'],
  'WProducts':['PQ-4559678','7171523315','5505296117','755961146']}


results = []
for key in my_dict:
  for key2 in my_dict:
    if key != key2:
      intersection = set.intersection(set(my_dict[key]), set(my_dict[key2]))
      if len(intersection) > 0:
        if [key2, key] not in results and [key, key2] not in results:
          results.append([key, key2])

print(results)
```

Which outputs `[['Alc', 'FItems'], ['Alc', 'kuVItem'], ['FItems', 'kuVItem'], ['Products', 'WProducts']]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

**Full code for copying**

```
import itertools
dict_of_lists = {
    'a' : [1,3],
    'b' : [3,4],
    'c' : [3,6]
    }

def common_data(list1, list2):
    result = False

    # traverse in the 1st list
    for x in list1:

    # traverse in the 2nd list
        for y in list2:

            # if one common
            if x == y:
                result = True
                return result

    return result

result_list = list(map(dict, itertools.combinations(list_of_lists.items(), 2)))
print(result_list)
pairs_commons_elements = []

for element in result_list:

    if(common_data(list_of_lists[list(element.keys())[0]],list_of_lists[list(element.keys())[1]])):
        pairs_common_elements.append(list(element.keys()))

print(pairs_common_elements)
```

**Explanation**

First, I'd put all your lists in a dict of lists, I did these for a more generic answer since an answer for your specific question has already been given.

```
dict_of_lists = {
'a' : [1,3],
'b' : [3,4],
'c' : [3,6]
}
```

We define 'common data' for checking if the two lists have any elements in common:

```
def common_data(list1, list2):
    result = False

    # traverse in the 1st list
    for x in list1:

    # traverse in the 2nd list
        for y in list2:

            # if one common
            if x == y:
                result = True
                return result

    return result
```

To be able to  use this function, we need to first make a list of every possible pair of the dict's keys (itertools.combinations() manages this):

```
result_list = list(map(dict, itertools.combinations(list_of_lists.items(), 2)))
```

Finally, we iterate through every possible pair and check if they have any element in common. If they do, we add them to the pairsCommonElements list.

```
pairs_common_elements = []
    
    if(common_data(list_of_lists[list(element.keys())[0]],list_of_lists[list(element.keys())[1]])):
        pairs_common_elements.append(list(element.keys()))

print(pairs_common_elements)
```

This outputs `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]`